# Cannot Delete All Azure Website Connection Strings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

For a website my team are currently working on we're trying to write some PowerShell automation to temporarily override a connection string which is otherwise usually in Web.config, and then at a later point delete it.

However, using both the PowerShell cmdlets and the Azure REST APIs, we don't seem to be able to ever reset the connection strings set to be empty. Whenever we try to delete it either the command says it succeeds but doesn't delete it, or the requests is rejected as invalid.

It's possible to delete all the connection strings using the Management Portal, so what are we missing that means we can't do it programmatically?

Here's an example PowerShell command we're using that isn't doing what we want:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebsite $websiteName -slot $websiteSlot
$connectionStrings = $website.ConnectionStrings

$result = $connectionStrings.Remove(($connectionStrings | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $connectionStringName}))

Set-AzureWebsite $websiteName -slot $websiteSlot -ConnectionStrings $connectionStrings
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Microsoft have recently stated that the new Azure portal is driven by the same public APIs, so how is it possible to delete settings from the UI but not through PowerShell? What is it that the UI does to delete settings?

Comment: I don't know, you would have to ask MSFT.  But, this should work IMO.  BTW, here is a link to an issue I opened last night on this if you want to follow. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/340

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is really late.

I have faced the same situation.We are able to update the App settings but not the connection strings.I found the solution.Since it doesn't have an answer, I thought it would be good to update it..

As per the [git-hub source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/Websites/Commands.Websites/Cmdlets/WebApps/SetAzureWebApp.cs#L65), the hash-table(nested) needs to be in the format of

```
@{ KeyName = @{ Type = "MySql"; Value = "MySql Connection string"}};
```

after which I ran the code to update the App, it worked. Below is the whole code

```
$list =  @{ ConnectionString1 = @{ Type = "MySql"; Value = "MySql Connection string"}};

set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup" -Name "devTest" -ConnectionStrings $list -slot "production"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way which bypasses the parameter requirements of the `Set-AzWebAppSlot` cmdlet by passing the entire modified object.

```
$foo = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $Group -Name $AppName -Slot $SlotName

# Scriptblock coerced to predicate which always resolves true.
$foo.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings.RemoveAll({ $True })
$foo | Set-AzWebAppSlot
```