# Automatically create new connection strings for web applications Azure

Tags: sql, powershell, azure

I am attempting to automate a workflow in our Azure environment.

We have several web applications with connectionstrings to several databases. Each new customer recives a new database.

I've hit a snag in the script with our connectionstrings. I want the script to update all web applications and add a new connectionstring for the newly created customer db.

The problem is `"Set-Azurermwebapp -Name -ResourceGroup -ConnectionStrings"` takes a hashtable which replaces any previously configured data.

I would only like to append a new connectionstring, or get the previously configered cstrings and add them to an array, then replacing all data.

Example code;

```
$test= @{"Type"="Custom"; "Value" = "TestValue"} 
$Connectionstring=@{"test"=$test }

Set-AzureRmWebApp 
        -Name "testapp" 
        -ResourceGroupName "testgrp" 
        -ConnectionStrings $Connectionstring"
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 10):

```
$connStrings =  @{ 
   AzureWebJobsDashboard = @{ 
       Type = "Custom"; 
       Value = $AzureWebJobsDashboard 
   };
   AzureWebJobsStorage = @{ 
       Type = "MySql"; 
       Value = $connstring
   }
};

Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name $webServiceName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ConnectionStrings $connStrings
```

[Cannot Delete All Azure Website Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648327/cannot-delete-all-azure-website-connection-strings)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks Srinivasa.

Comment: Thanks @Srinivasa-Rao-Nalluri. I had hard time to find a good and simple example like yours. Perfect !

Comment: surely this just overwrites all existing connection strings? the OP wanted to know how to add new ones without removing any existing ones

Comment: I agree that Azure Powershell could be better at achieving this, you need to add all existing values to the hashtable, as it does a full overwrite for your webapp. Also makes it harder that when you get the values from the Get-AzureRmWebApp for example, the Siteconfig.ConnectionStrings property is a list, but when setting the values you need a hashtable as parameter. Maybe these were made by different teams at Microsoft without communication : )

Answer (score 0):

```
#Add new connection string
$newConnString = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Websites.Services.WebEntities.ConnStringInfo
$newConnString.Name = $ConnStringName
$newConnString.ConnectionString = $ConnStringValue
$newConnString.Type = $ConnStringType
$connStrings.Add($newConnString)

Set-AzureWebsite $WebAppName -ConnectionStrings $connStrings
```

You can download detail script from [How to automatically create new connection strings for web applications Azure](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-automatically-d031b956)